# Formal deduction proof of predicates

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I am trying to proof equality is transitive, that is,

$\emptyset \vdash \forall x \forall y \forall z ((x=y) \land (y=z) \to(x=z))$

using formal deduction (17 rules) and also other rules (ex.

To begin, I thought of using $\to$elimination to get the 2 separate clauses

$\sum \vdash(x=y) \land (y=z)$

$\sum \vdash(x=z)$

and then using $\land$elimination to further simplify it to

$\sum \vdash(x=y),(y=z)$

but I am not sure of how to proceed from this step. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

17 rules:
[image]

Comment: I think it is not $∀x∃y∀z$ but $∀x∀y∀z$.

Answer (score 0):

1) $x=y \vdash x=y$ --- Rule 1

2) $\vdash x=x$ --- $=$-intro

3) $x=y \vdash y=x$ --- from 1) and 2) by $=$-elim, with $A(x) := y=x$

4) $x=y, y=z \vdash y=x$ --- from 3) by Rule 2

5) $x=y, y=z \vdash y=z$ --- Rules 1 and 2

> 6) $x=y, y=z \vdash x=z$ --- from 4) and 5) by $=$-elim, with $A(y) := y=z$.

Comment: what does this symbol mean ":="

Comment: @Bill - is a way to say: "let $A(y)$ be ...", in order to avoid mixing it with the $=$ sign.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to show this. I am using a Fitch-style proof checker to make sure I am following the rules.

[image]

On the first line I assume the names, $a$, $b$ and $c$, have the identity relationships specified by the antecedent of the conditional I want to derive.

On line 4, I use identity elimination (=E). See chapter 24 of the *forallx* text for a discussion of identity. Given line 2, $a$ can be substituted for $b$. That substitution is used in line 3 to derive line 4.

Conditional introduction occurs on line 5 which discharges the assumption on line 1. After that each of the universally quantified variables are introduced to reach the goal.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: In the format preferred by the original poster, that would be: $$\begin{array}{rrll}1.&(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)&\vdash(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)&\text{Ref}\\2.&(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)&\vdash(s=t_1)&\land~E,1\\3.&(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)&\vdash(t_1=t_2)&\land~ E,1\\4.&(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)&\vdash(s=t_2)&=E,2,3\\5.&&\vdash(s=t_1)\land(t_1=t_2)\to(s=t_2)&\to I,4\\6.&&\vdash\forall z~((s=t_1)\land(t_1=z)\to(s=z))&\forall~ I,5\\7.&&\vdash\forall y~\forall z~((s=y)\land(y=z)\to(s=z))&\forall~ I,6\\8.&&\vdash\forall x~\forall y~\forall z~((x=y)\land(y=z)\to(x=z))&\forall~ I,8\end{array}$$